# SD Card Video is not playing?

Tags: android, sd-card, android-videoview

I am not able to play video file from SD Card.
- I am playing particular video file from SD Card.
-while select video from list it will not playing video.
-what i am passing intent to videoView class is not reading.

```
public class AndroidThumbnailList extends ListActivity{

String[] videoFileList = {
        "/sdcard/Periodontal/Perio-Probling.mp4",
        "/sdcard/Periodontal/Inlays.mp4"
        /*  "/sdcard/Video/Onlays.mp4",
        "/sdcard/Video/Root Canal Treatment.mp4",
        "/sdcard/Video/crown4.mp4",
        "/sdcard/Video/crown5.mp4",
        "/sdcard/Video/crown6.mp4",
        "/sdcard/Video/crown7.mp4"*/
};

public class MyThumbnaildapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row = convertView;
        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        }


        row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(position==0)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidThumbnailList.this, ViewVideo.class);
                    intent.putExtra("videofilename", videoFileList);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                    /*if(position==1)
                {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PeriodontalCare.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);                         


                }
                        if(position==2)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, CosmeticCare.class);

                    mContext.startActivity(i);

                }*/
            }
        });
        TextView textfilePath = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.FilePath);
        textfilePath.setText(videoFileList[position]);

        ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);

        Bitmap bmThumbnail;
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFileList[position], Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

        return row;
    }

}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new MyThumbnaildapter(AndroidThumbnailList.this, R.layout.row, videoFileList));
}
```

}

My VideoView class:

```
public class ViewVideo extends Activity {
  private String videoFileList;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // setContentView(R.layout.videofile);

        //    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);



        System.gc();
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        videoFileList = extras.getString("videofilename");
        VideoView vv = new VideoView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(vv);
        vv.setVideoPath(videoFileList);
        vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        vv.requestFocus();
        vv.start();
  }
```

}

Comment: don't use an onClickListener on the grid item. Use the onItemSelected (or something) provided by the grid view. Because your row object is reused.

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't create a new `VideoView`, but get the `VideoView` using `findViewById`:

   ```
   setContentView(R.layout.videofile);
   VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
   // rest of the calls on vv
   ```
2. You shouldn't use a hardcoded path to the video file, as it may change between different devices. Instead, use something like that.

   ```
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Periodontal/Perio-Probling.mp4"
   ```

Comment: Hi Binyamin,Thanks for the reply-Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Periodontal/Perio-Probling.mp4" -its only for single file can i read if i want read more than one file?

Comment: This is only an example, to demonstrate the usage of the method, use it whenever you need it (or create a String variable that contains the method result)